# Можно ли где-то онлайн протестировать сайт на высоких dpi?

Tags: тестирование, веб-программирование

Например, чтобы увидеть, как будет выглядеть сайт на retina (с удвоенной плотностью пикселей), если доступ к настоящим айфонам отсутствует?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### С помощью Firefox

> 1) Откройте адрес "about:config" и подтвердите изменение настроек
> 2)  Найдите параметр "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx" и смените его значение на 2
> 3)  Перейдите на нужную страницу или обновите текущую
>
> Чтобы вернуть стандартный режим, нужно сменить значение этого же параметра на 1.

#### С помощью Google Chrome

> [О встроенной эмуляции ретина-устройств](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation)